# Syntax for UIAction on Xcode 11 beta 3

Tags: swift, xcode11, ios13

Xcode 11 beta 3 does not accept this code to instantiate `UIAction` anymore:

```
let action = UIAction(__title: "title", image: someImage, options: []) { _ in
    // some action
}
```

There's nothing in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaction) either.

I've found [a post on Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119189) describing this same problem and the syntax that's now accepted, but it results in a runtime error:

```
let action = UIAction(__title: "title", image: someImage, identifier: nil, handler: { _ in
    // some action
}
```

`+[UIAction actionWithTitle:image:identifier:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fffa1b30178`

There's also this new parameter `identifier`, but I couldn't find any documentation about how to use it.

Has anyone been able to successfully use `UIAction` with Xcode 11 beta 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're getting the `options` parameter from. This compiles and runs (no crash) on my machine using Xcode 11 beta 3:

```
    let action = UIAction(__title: "Howdy", image: nil, identifier: nil) {
        _ in
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps your installation of Xcode 11 beta 3 or the simulator is flawed? I recommend deleting all simulators and starting over every time you download a new version of Xcode, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I've tried on the iPad Pro simulator and it works! I think the problem is on my iPhone 7 Plus, which did not receive iOS 13 beta 3.

Comment: Reading the release notes is good: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_3_release_notes iOS 13 beta 3 isn’t available for iPhone 7 or iPhone 7 Plus. (52363318)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/ and goto time 44:46.